# how can you enter a float in pyautogui.prompt() ??? with python

Tags: python, pyautogui, floating

i can only enter int or str in a pyautogui.prompt field. Is there a way to enter a float?

Thankfull for any Help...

Tom

I tried entering a float for an expected winning rate calculater in python, but could only enter int or str.